# Error while doing SFTP from as400 server

Tags: ibm-midrange

Actually when i am putting command sftp -vvv user@server.com and when it is trying to connect it is converting @ to a junk symbol as '§'.

And its trying to connect as user§server.com.

So can you help me for this issue.

Following is log:

```
sftp -vvv user@server.com
Connecting to user§server.com...
OpenSSH_4.7p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/SC1/OpenSSH/openssh-4.7p1//etc/ssh_config
debug3: RNG is ready, skipping seeding
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv0
ssh: user\247server.com: Hostname and service name not provided or found
Connection closed   
$
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a character encoding issue but you haven't provided enough information about how you are executing the command to identify the exact problem.

As a workaround you can pass the `-oUser=` parameter to specify the username.

```
sftp -vvv -oUser=user server.com
```